# Particionamento tabelas MYSQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, database-partitioning

Boa noite a todos.

Tenho uma duvida referente a tabelas no mysql.

Supondo o seguinte cenário.

Tenho uma tabela MYSQL INNODB com PK ID  INT UNSIGNED. ( 4 bilhoes de registros aprox)

1 º Se por ventura eu chegar no registro 4.294.967.295,00  nao vai inserir correto?

2 º Se eu particionar essa tabela no MYSQL tipo Partition Key em por exemplo 200 particoes, o numero de registros é ilimitado ?

tipo tenho  4.294.967.295,00  x 200 (partições) no caso podendo chegar até 
858.993.459.000,00 registros.  É isso ou nada a ver ?

Estou com receio de ultrapassar o limite do INT UNSIGNED, e nao gostaria de usar BIG INT UNSIGNED ou nvarchar.

Obrigado!

Comment: Olhei na documentação mas não tenho certeza para responder. Na dúvida eu usaria o tipo de dados que cabe mais dados. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html

Comment: Eu não tenho experiência com particionamento nem nunca lidei com uma tabela tão grande, mas em teoria BIGINT suportaria 2^64-1 registros. Ver https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Mas a performance fica comprometida com BigInt no momento de fazer selects com tabelas com mais de 2 milhoes de registros ou 10 milhoes.